# Dealing with the horizontal line when using the position property in css with some elements

Tags: html, css

I made a couple of squares as an application on the (z-index) property , and used the (position:relative;) with the parent and the (position: absolute;) with the children . Then I wanted to add a horizontal line just to start another thing on the webpage (just to make a visual separation for myself ) . What really surprised me is that the horizontal line when I change the value of it's margin property , the  horizontal line pulls the shapes with it even if I assigned a big value to the margin . Then I thought of changing the display of the horizontal line from the default value (which is block) to the value (inline-block) . And surprisingly , what I wanted worked . The horizontal line changed it's place by changing the margin without pulling the squares  with it . I really don't understand why using the (display: block;) made the horizontal line pull the squares while changing it's place .
Any reference to the documentation would be great because I didn't know what to write to search for something like that in the documentation .

The used code :

```css
.one {
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

.green,
.red,
.blue,
.black {
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.green {
  background-color: rgb(0, 150, 136);
  z-index: 3;
}

.red {
  background-color: rgb(244, 67, 54);
  z-index: 4;
  margin: 10px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: rgb(3, 169, 244);
  z-index: 2;
  margin: -8px;
}

.black {
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  z-index: 1;
  /* margin: -6px;
        margin-left: -8px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right: 11px; */
  margin: 0px 11px -6px -8px;
  /* I used the shorthand of the (margin property ) so I commented some of the 
    above lines .  */
}

hr {
  height: 6px;
  background-color: khaki;
  margin-top: 124px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  /* I gave the display the value of (inline-block) because the horizontal line
        kept pulling the DIVs over it when I changed it's margin to make it move . */
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: Go read up on _collapsing margins_.

Comment: Okay , I learned about the margin collpasing because I didn't know it before ,  Thanks for refering to that . The problem is that I still don't understand why when assigning different values for the display property the shapes deal in different ways . Why when using (display: block;) the squares stick to the horizontal line , while when using (display: inline-block;) the elements behave as I want and do not stick to each other

Comment: While I agree the behavior you are seeing is somewhat counter-intuitive and I can't explain it, it's perhaps worth noting that the hr element is (now) intended to have semantic rather than purely decorative meaning (see MDN) and is intended to be used between paragraph-level blocks.

Comment: Yes I understand now . Thanks for explaining !  I found this on MDN :   (Historically, this has been presented as a horizontal rule or line. While it may still be displayed as a horizontal rule in visual browsers, this element is now defined in semantic terms, rather than presentational terms, so if you wish to draw a horizontal line, you should do so using appropriate CSS.)